# Xamarin form Command Parameter object is null passing from a template view

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am implementing list view with MVVM and have tap recogniser for the label. I have a custom template for displaying the cell. I am following tutorials on binding the command.  I managed to bind the command but could not figure out how to bind Command Property. My command property is always null.

My list view is like this

```
***** For anyone looking for the solution. Before this line I had a grid view 
like below
<Grid x:DataType="viewModels:CartViewModel"> 

************************************************

   <ListView
                            ItemsSource="{Binding CartItem.Products}"
                            HasUnevenRows="True"
                            SeparatorVisibility="None"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ViewCell>
                                        <templates:CartItemTemplate
                                            RemoveItemCommand="{Binding BindingContext.RemoveCartItemCommand, Source={x:Reference Cart}}"
                                            UpdateCartCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                            AddCommentCommand="{Binding BindingContext.AddCommentCommand, Source={x:Reference Cart}}"
                                            UpdateCartCommand="{Binding BindingContext.UpdateCartCommand, Source={x:Reference Cart}}"
                                            />
                                    </ViewCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

And my template is like this. Other codes are omitted.

```
<Label
                            Text="Update cart"
                            TextDecorations="Underline"
                            Margin="8, 0, 0, 0"
                            FontSize="12"
                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    Command="{Binding UpdateCartCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding UpdateCartCommandParameter}"/>
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>
```

In the code behind of that template I have done like this

```
public static readonly BindableProperty UpdateCartCommandProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(UpdateCartCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(CartItemTemplate));

        public ICommand UpdateCartCommand
        {
            get => (ICommand) GetValue(UpdateCartCommandProperty);
            set => SetValue(UpdateCartCommandProperty, value);
        }

        public static BindableProperty UpdateCartCommandParameterProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(UpdateCartCommandParameter), typeof(Product), typeof(CartItemTemplate));

        public Product UpdateCartCommandParameter
        {
            get => (Product) GetValue(UpdateCartCommandParameterProperty);
            set => SetValue(UpdateCartCommandParameterProperty, value);
        }
```

And finally in my MVVM code. I have implemented this.

```
        public ICommand UpdateCartCommand { get; }

        

        private readonly ICartService cartService;
        private readonly INavigationService navigationService;
        public CartPageViewModel(ICartService cartService, INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            this.cartService = cartService;
            this.navigationService = navigationService;
       
            UpdateCartCommand = new Command<object>(UpdateCartClicked);
           
        }

       
        private async void UpdateCartClicked(object cartItem)
        {
            await navigationService.ShowAlertAsync("Update Action", "Update cart quantity", "Ok");
        }
```

The problem is object cartItem is always null. What am I doing wrong here? Any idea will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: It seems that You used third party library . So you could share a sample so that I can test it on my side directly .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have only used tinyIoC for dependency. Other than are the nativ e code.

Comment: Could you share a sample which contains the issue ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have created a git repo with the project. Link is https://github.com/bikrambhandari48/Storefront.git . Let me know if you can download this or not. If you go to Cart page and in the list if you click the update cart label. Then you can recreate the issue.

Comment: I had tested your sample , and can reproduce the issue . However , it works on normal ContentPage and MVVM logic(it even work if I set the parameter as static data) . So I could make sure if the issue caused by the logic in BaseViewModel . You could test your code in a new blank project .

Comment: Yes the binding parameter works correctly if I move the template content to the main page. Not sure what is causing this. I don't think the issue is in BaseViewModel. Let me know if you have any other idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221565/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-jivan-bhandari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoked the line like following which is illegal .

```
 x:DataType="viewModels:CartPageViewModel"
```

Compiled bindings are currently disabled for any binding expressions that define the Source property. This is because the Source property is always set using the **x:Reference** markup extension, which can't be resolved at compile time.

If you want to set **BindingContext** in Xaml , use the following code

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:xxxViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Comment: Although I don't understand what you are trying to say. But this fixed the issue. Thank you very much